# Testing In-App Purchase Works on One Device and not Another

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, ios-provisioning

Ok so I have an in-app purchase sandbox testing fine on an old iPod touch. Just got a new iPhone, added it to the provisioning profile I was using for this project, re-downloaded it and added it to xcode. The transaction is failing whenever I test it out on the iPhone, whereas it still works fine on the iPod touch... wtf?

Comment: Same version of iOS on both devices?

Comment: My guess is that therein lies your answer. You're probably using deprecated code where.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your iOS developer account can active a "test account" on only one device at a time. You have to disable the test account on the first device and re-enable it on the second. That's probably the problem — it certainly happens to me. ;-)

Comment: So what should I do? Just log out on the other one? That alone doesn't fix it.

Comment: It's as uneasy as unregistering and reregistering from the dev portal. :-(

Comment: So set up a new test user? The login prompt never even shows up on the new device.